# .findall Regular Expression won't assign to a variable

Tags: python, regex, nlp, findall

I'm trying to create a function that searches a chunk of nltk.text.Text input and outputs all words following "contribute" or "donate" (see the regular expression below).

The regular expression works perfectly, however when I try to assign it to a variable in order for my function to return it, the variable doesn't update and my function returns nothing.

i.e. type(donation) = NoneType object

I eventually want to apply this function to every row of a data frame and output the donation value to a new column in that data frame, but when I try it now, every output is "None"

```
def find_donation_orgs(x):
    text = nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(x))
    donation =  text.findall(r"<\.> <.*>{,15}? <donat.*|contrib.*|Donat.*|Contrib.*> <.*>*? <to> (<.*>+?) <\.|\,|\;> ")
    return donation
```

My findall regex does work by itself:

```
text.findall(r"<\.> <.*>{,15}? <donat.*|contrib.*|Donat.*|Contrib.*> <.*>*? <to> (<.*>+?) <\.|\,|\;> ")
```

Returns this for an example piece of text:

```
visit brother Alfred Fuller; the research of Dr. Giuseppe Giaccone at
Georgetown University
```

For your benefit:

```
text = nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(df.Obit.iloc[7]))
print(text)

x = text.findall(r"<\.> <.*>{,15}? <donat.*|contrib.*|Donat.*|Contrib.*> <.*>*? <to> (<.*>+?) <\.|\,|\;> ")

print(x)
```

Returns:

```
<Text: M. Jay Janssen , age 95 of Zeeland...>
Resthaven Care Community
None
```

Comment: are you sure that your regex works? a return of `NoneType` usually implies no matches

Comment: yep, it works on its own... see update above

Comment: oddly enough, if you look at the [docs](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html), using `Text.findall` doesnt actually RETURN anything, it just prints it. instead, it looks like passing in your `Text` object to a `TokenSearcher` object and calling `.findall` on the `TokenSearcher` will actually return your matches

Comment: The regex is too greedy, I'd replace all `.*` with `[>]*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As R Nar noted above .findall regex only prints and doesn't return anything... TokenSearcher solves the problem perfectly... it does output a list of tokens as opposed to a string, but does the job.

```
from nltk.text import TokenSearcher

def find_donation_orgs(x):
    text = nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(x))
    donation = TokenSearcher(text).findall(r"<\.> <.*>{,15}? <donat.*|contrib.*|Donat.*|Contrib.*> <.*>*? <to> (<.*>+?) <\.|\,|\;> ")
    return donation
```